# unix command 'tail' lost option '--line-buffered'

Tags: unix, streaming, tail

With the last update of our SuSE Enterprise Linux 11 (now bash 3.2.51(1)-release), the command "tail" seems to have lost its option to stream files:

```
tail: unrecognized option '--line-buffered'
```

Our tail is from "GNU coreutils 8.12, March 2013". Is there another, equivalent solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as can be told by simple googling, `tail` doesn't appear to have a `--line-buffered` option, `grep` does. `--line-buffered` is useful to force line buffering even when writing to a non-TTY, a typical idiom being:

```
tail -f FILE | grep --line-buffered REGEXP > output
```

Here the point of `--line-buffered` is to prevent `grep` from buffering output in 8K chunks and forcing the matched lines to immediately appear in the output file.

`tail -f` is unbuffered regardless of output type, so it doesn't need a `--line-buffered` option equivalent to the one in `grep`. This can be verified by running `tail -f somefile | cat` and appending a line to the file from another shell. One observes that, despite its standard output being a pipe, `tail` immediately flushes the newly arrived line.

Comment: `tail` waits for a *newline*, though.

Comment: @devnull That's not what I see. On my system (tail 8.13), `tail -f foo | cat` followed by `printf xxx >> foo` in another shell immediately shows `xxx` on the tail/cat output screen. And even if `tail` did wait for a newline, but `--line-buffered` would not help with that.

Comment: If I `tail -f` a few files simultenously the output is *not* line-buffered, but a garbled combination of the input if those files are being appended in a parallel fashion. E.g. tailing a few log files.

Actually, the tailing a number of files and handing their output over to grep in a line-buffered fashion is  a problem that does not seem to have a simple solution at all. And that is all because the tail does not have the `--line-buffered` option.

Comment: @TommiKyntola "Line buffered" only means that no output is written sent to the OS (using `write(2)`) until a newline is seen. You seem to be using the term in a different and non-standard sense, meaning "don't mix incomplete lines from separate files". While such line-based output coherency would be a very useful feature when tailing multiple log files, it has nothing to do with line buffering as normally understood.

Comment: Well, yes. Line buffering is not the same thing as what I'd like to have there, but it would solve the problem and `-f` does *not* imply line-buffering either, contrary to what you claim up there. The `tail -f` is _unbuffered_. Try this, touch a file, cat it in a terminal, `echo -n` into it a few times and watch them being flushed out. The difference is not severe with a single file, but when you have multple files, like in my log example, the difference is catastrophic.

Comment: @TommiKyntola Good catch, I've now corrected the erroneous claim in the response.