# How can I tail -f but only in whole lines?

Tags: unix, tail

I have a constantly updating huge log file  (MainLog).

I want to create another file which is only the last n lines of the log file BUT also updating.

If I use:

> tail -f MainLog > RecentLog

I get ALMOST what I want except RecentLog is written as MainLog is available and might at any point only have part of the last MainLog line.

How can I specify to tail that I only want it to write when a WHOLE line is available?

Comment: I think you want to investigate `logrotate`...

Answer (score 1):

By default, tail outputs whole lines unless you use the -c switch to count characters.   Something like

```
 tail -n 20 -f MainLog > RecentLog
```

(substituting the number of lines you want prepended to the second file for "20") should work as you want.

But if if doesn't, it is possible that using grep to line-buffer your output will fix this condition.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227308/unix-command-tail-lost-option-line-buffered).

Comment: I am pretty sure it is - I think it is a feature of tail. Any ideas how to ensure only whole lines are written?

Comment: That may work for a single watched file, but it definitely does not prevent the breaking up and mangling of lines when following multiple log files (`tail -f log1 log2`). See my answer for a solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, the only solution for *multiple files* that worked (fantastically well) for me is the [fdlinecombine](https://github.com/vi/fdlinecombine) command. It's a small binary that reads multiple file descriptors and prints data to stdout linewise.

My use case is spawning multiple long-running `ssh` commands in the background and following their output, without having the lines garbled or interrupted in between.